# Find prime factors in C++

Tags: c++, primes, factors

Please review this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool is_prime(int x)
{
    int flag = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= x/2; i++)
    {
        if (x % i == 0)
        {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (flag == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

void find_prime_factors(int n, std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    int val = n;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (is_prime(i))
        {
            while (val % i == 0 && val != 1)
            {
                vec.push_back(i);
                val = val/i;
            }
            if (val == 1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter number\n";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> prime_factors;
    find_prime_factors(n, prime_factors);
    std::cout << "Prime Factors of " << n << ":\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < prime_factors.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << prime_factors[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: In your loop checking for prime you iterate to x/2 which does not represent the square root as you intend. Technically the loop should still cover the desired range. i * i <= x would be more optimal. Or while(i * i <= x)

Comment: @Summer, `i * i` is at risk of overflow.  Consider `i <= x / i` instead - or, for better performance, see `greater_than_sqrt()` in [this question](/q/286696/75307).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your program has a bug. `is_prime` returns `true` in all possible `return` situations. You don't notice that because your prime factors already use a nice property of prime factors which we inspect later. Here's a short list of improvements first:

1. `return condition` instead of `if condition return true; else return false;`
2. `return` early.
3. Use appropriate return types.
4. Modify algorithms.

Now let's focus on the bug first.

## `is_prime`

First, the obvious: both `return` statements only return `true`. However, there are some improvements we can apply. First, if two conditions are exclusive and cover the whole range of possible conditions use `if/else` without a second if:

```
if (flag == 1)
{
    return true;
}
else // no if here!
{
    return true;
}
```

Note that this still contains your bug above. This brings us to our next improvement: instead of

```
if (condition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

just `return condition`:

```
return (flag == 1);
```

Note that this completely removes the bug already. But we can go further. `flag` itself introduces a source for possible bugs. We could accidentally use `flag = 3` (which can be mediated by `bool flag`) or forget to set `flag` (which can be checked by statical analysis).

But we don't need `flag`. Either we `break` the loop (and therefore `flag = 0`) and we return `false`, or we won't and return `true`. This is a perfect opportunity to use early `return`s:

```
bool is_prime(int x)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= x/2; i++)
    {
        if (x % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

There are two optimizations that are left for exercise. First, we don't need to check every `i`, but only every second. If `x % 2 != 0`, then `x % i != 0` for all even `i`. Also, for any pair of factors \$ab=x\$ holds \$a\le b\$ and therefore \$a\le \sqrt{x}\$. Both optimizations are left as an exercise.

## `find_prime_factors`

We now have a look at 3., "use appropriate return types". Your function's result is a vector. Nothing in its interface prevents a user to supply an already filled vector, e.g.:

```
std::vector<int> example = {1,2,3,4,5};
find_prime_factors(10, example); // whoops!
```

So instead have `find_prime_factors` *return* its result:

```
std::vector<int> find_prime_factors(int n)
{
    int val = n;
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (is_prime(i))
        {
            while (val % i == 0 && val != 1)
            {
                result.push_back(i);
                val = val/i;
            }
            if (val == 1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Next, we'll focus on the algorithm. As you noticed, `find_prime_factors` worked, even though `is_prime` is broken. Why?

When you divide a number by its smallest prime factor, the next number that will divide the new number **must** be a prime factor. Let's try it by hand:

$$
\begin{align}
420 &= 2\cdot 2 \cdot 105 &\text{ the next factor is } 3 \\
&= 2\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 35 &\text{ the next factor is } 5 \\
&= 2\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 &\text{ the next factor is } 7 \\
&= 2\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 1
\end{align}
$$
We don't need the `is_prime` check at all:

```
std::vector<int> find_prime_factors(int n)
{
    int val = n;
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        while (val % i == 0 && val != 1)
        {
            result.push_back(i);
            val = val/i;
        }
        if (val == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Also, we can stop as soon as `i > val`, because at that point `val == 1`. 
 In fact, we can get rid of `val` altogether and just modify `n`:

```
std::vector<int> find_prime_factors(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        while (n % i == 0)
        {
            result.push_back(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

At some point `n == i` and `n /= i` will yield `n == 1`, so we don't have to worry about an infinite loop. This algorithm is also known as [trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division). Note that we can also apply the optimization for even numbers here (left as another exercise).

There are other optimizations that one can apply:

- reserve memory beforehand (a number \$N\$ can have at most \$\log_2 N\$ factors, so `std::vector::reserve` can be used)
- use methods that yields both quotient and divisor at the same time (very platform specific).

For a fun exercise, you can rewrite it with iterators in mind:

```
template <typename OutputIt> OutputIt(int n, OutputIt out) {
    // exercise
}
```

Note that this is somewhat an overkill, since `n` will contain at most 64 prime factors if your `int` uses 64 bits.

## Bottom line

Check *all* your functions. `is_prime` contained a nasty bug. Other than that your code is nicely structured, doesn't use `using namespace` and was easy to read.

Comment: Unfortunately gcc and clang are dumb and don't take advantage of division producing the modulo for free and vice versa, so there are actually two `idiv` instructions in the inner loop unless you mangle the source code to hand-hold the compilers into not sucking.  reported https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85366 and https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37101.  BTW, you mentioned not checking even numbers > 2 for primality, but worth mentioning it again for the trial-division loop in `find_prime_factors`.  Current compilers also fail to optimize that for you.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, compilers are somewhat dumb. I'll add a `std::div` remark.

Comment: IDIV is x86 specific, though. ARM's Cortex-M3 for example don't store the remainder, and `std::div` can lead to a small overhead there. I'll check GCC's `std::div` implementation later today.

Comment: x86 isn't the only ISA that produces div and mod in one instruction.  (e.g. MIPS uses the lo/hi regs for output from division).  Even on ARM, if you need both you'd want to divide, then multiply and subtract instead of running a separate modulo instruction.   Compilers are fine at CSEing `x / y` and `x % y` when they're in the same block; so normally `std::div` is pure loss because it doesn't typically inline, and the x86-64 SysV calling convention requires it to pack both 32-bit members into RAX.  But it's a win here if you don't want to make the source ugly: https://godbolt.org/g/zET9YY

Comment: AArch64 has `msub`  to do the multiply and subtract after an `sdiv`, so gcc ends up doing a great job there: https://godbolt.org/g/KNT4NB.  AArch32 `-mcpu=cortex-m3` also uses `sdiv` / `mls` to do the same thing.      (Both included on the Godbolt link).  So calling `std::div` is definitely worse than getting the compiler to inline good code; I'm hesitant to recommend it.  But for AArch32 without specifying a target CPU, you get braindead code that calls `__aeabi_idiv` and then `__aeabi_idivmod`, xD.

Comment: @PeterCordes That godbolt explorer. Wow. Thanks for that! I usually use Coliru, but that focuses more on running the code. Either way, as usual, only optimize what you have measured, so even though we use one (or some) instructions too much, we're somewhat going for an overkill for this algorithm :)

Comment: That's true if you care about this specific program (which we don't).  But I'm worried about the quality of gcc and clang, for the benefit of any similar code out there where people assume that compilers will be able to handle `n % i` and `n / i` efficiently, or didn't think about it.  For simple cases like this, removing an `idiv` doesn't really need to be benchmarked to see it's a pure win on x86.  (It's maybe a minor win on Intel CPUs with pipelined divide, like SnB.  But Ryzen's `idiv` isn't pipelined at all: throughput=latency=14..30 cycles, so it's huge there. http://agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: Hmm, on Intel you have to go back to Core2 to find a mainstream CPU where `idiv r32` throughput isn't at least about twice as good as latency.  So that's too old to [simulate with IACA](//stackoverflow.com/q/26021337).  But Silvermont's `idiv` is only slightly pipelined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75890/discussion-between-zeta-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: Very detailed review. Thanks for the effort @Zeta

Comment: I would note that there is a usecase for letting the user supply the `vector` as argument => buffer reuse. In modern C++, I would take the `vector` by rvalue-reference (preventing accidental copy) and return it. Of course, the first step is to clear the `vector` in case it's not empty.

Comment: @MatthieuM. you could argue pro-iterators by the same argument, though, e.g. `template <typename OutputIt> OutputIt find_prime_factors(int n, OutputIt out)`. That will enable buffer-reuse (either via `data`, pointer, `back_inserter`), printing (via `ostream_iterator`) and so on.

Comment: @Zeta: Sure, that's one more step. However I find it inconsistent to recommend using `std::div` to optimize division/multiplication to optimize performance, when the code is allocating memory (multiple times) which may run afoul of thread contention, or even perform an OS call. In terms of order of magnitude, memory allocation is usually much worse than a few divisions/modulos in terms of possible performance issues/gains.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Full ACK. I think I'll edit my answer later, currently mobile.

Answer (score 4):

When I wrote my answer I thought it was different to the accepted answer. After rereading the accepted answer, I realised the algorithm presented in both are actually the same. I decided to leave my answer here since the explanation and presentation is different.

This answer focuses on a short simple solution to the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  int n;
  std::cout << "Enter number\n";
  std::cin >> n;
  for (int p = 2; n > 1 && p <= n; p++)
  {
    while (n % p == 0)
    {
      std::cout << p << " ";
      n /= p;
    }
  }
  std::cout << n << "\n";
}
```

In the solution, we see no mention of primes whatsoever, it appears we're testing every value of p between 2..n, and that's correct. We are. However, the result is always a list of primes? Why?

When the program begins, and you enter 420, it tries "2"...

```
n    p    output       n'    p'   description
420  2    2            210   2    2 goes into 420
210  2    2 2          105   2    2 goes into 210
105  2    2 2          105   3    2 doesn't go into 105 move to next 'prime'
105  3    2 2 3        35    3    3 goes into 105
35   3    2 2 3        35    4    3 doesn't go into 35 move to next 'prime'
35   4    2 2 3        35    5    4 doesn't go into 35 move to next 'prime'
35   5    2 2 3 5      7     5    5 goes into 35
7    5    2 2 3 5      7     6    5 doesn't go into 7 move to next 'prime'
7    6    2 2 3 5      7     7    6 doesn't go into 7 move to next 'prime'
7    7    2 2 3 5 7    1     7    7 goes into 7, and we terminate loop
```

So, we are in fact trying every number from 2..7, but, the reason why 4 and 6 don't get a hit, is because we had already removed 2 and 3 as factors earlier. In general terms, all non prime versions of `p` never get a hit because we already removed the related prime factors previously.

I put `std::cout << n << "\n"` at the end to show the residual value of `n`. Typically this will be just `1`. However, this is useful for handling edge conditions when the user enters `0`, `1` or a negative number. We simply return the user's input back to them, rather than showing them nothing.

bruglesco [suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191792/find-prime-factors-in-c#comment368230_191792) changing the terminating condition to `p*p <= n`, i.e.

```
  for (int p = 2; n > 1 && p*p <= n; p++)
```

Whilst this change, is very simple, it optimizes the algorithm dramatically meaning for an input like 97 we only test from 2..9 to realize that there's no point in checking any further. This makes the last line I added more pertinent, as it's no longer for edge condition, but, displays the last prime.

Comment: It's probably worth it to `sqrt` once instead of squaring every time time inside the loop, at least on modern CPUs that have fast floating-point sqrt hardware and fast conversion from int to double.  Or maybe not because sqrt will use the same divider hardware as trial-division, so out-of-order execution can't let the first few iterations get started while waiting for `p <= max_p` condition to evaluate.  And if you're lucky, a smart compiler will strength-reduce `p*p` to `psquared += p`.

Comment: Peter the max_p isnt constant since n is a moving/shrinking target. Computationally sqrt is more expensive than squaring. However having said that there's optimization possible to reduce the need for frequent squaring.